# Extract edges from igraph object

Tags: r, igraph

I have an igraph object:

```
a<-graph.lattice(dimvector = 100, length = NULL, dim = NULL, nei = 5,
              directed = FALSE, mutual = FALSE, circular = TRUE)
```

I would like to extract the edges from this graph using:

```
str(a)
```

and store it in a matrix.

My goal is to keep the format from the output of str().

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to give the same result as str() :

```
mx <- do.call(rbind, get.adjlist(a))
```

Comment: Not always, because `str()`'s output changes depending on the size of the graph.

Comment: @GaborCsardi: well, yes correct. But I hope the OP wants the full output not a truncated one ;)

Comment: That's not what I mean. The output is not always an adjacency list. For small graphs it is an edge list.